# Can I auto-rename all of the fields in a package using Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a bunch of auto-generated code and I need to rename the fields so they are start with a lowercase letter.  The best I can do so far is use `shift+F6` to do a rename refactoring one at a time.  There are about 30 classes though, so this manual process is too time consuming.  Is there a way to have Intellij run this refactoring against all the fields in classes within a given package?

**Here is an example class that needs refactoring:**

```
public class User   {
    private String Name;
}
```

**The desired result is:**

```
public class User   {
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that.  The refactoring tools tend to be localized to a single class as opposed to global for all classes in a package.

Comment: @Makoto are there any external tools that can do this?

Comment: None come to mind, but to be frank, doing that sort of global replacement isn't really a refactoring.  If it's the case that you're running into this issue with a lot of classes, you should deploy code inspection tools like PMD to catch these sorts of things.

Comment: I'd suspect a cleverly done bash script or something of the sort could do this, but I can't say I'm nearly good enough with that to say for sure

Comment: @Makoto Even the built-in Intellij code inspection can find these as Naming convention issues, I just wish it would provide an "apply fix" option.

Comment: You shouldn't change generated code, unless you *really* have to. Can you change the way it's generated instead? Failing that, have you tried simple find&replace?